# Why does Find My iPhone need to be disabled before restoring an iPhone?

Tags: ios, restore

If I try to restore from iTunes, it tells me I have to turn off find my iPhone. Why is this so?

Comment: If I answered your question, please mark it as an accepted answer. Unless there was something I didn't understand about your question.

Comment: @ChrisHarrington I know. I just was inactive yesterday.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Disabling Find My iPhone is required because otherwise someone could steal a phone and wipe it, and the owner wouldn't be able to do anything about it. When you disable Find My iPhone, it requires your Apple ID and password.